# Should we have a blanket question for "Is this hardware compatible with Ubuntu?"

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I know shopping recommendations are off-topic, but I think "Is this hardware compat" or "What hardware is compat" could have a useful answer that links to the Canonical certified hardware page.

A good question would be worded in a general way.  A good answer would make it clear that there IS other "working" hardware, but that asking if each individual piece of hardware works is off-topic.  If you want to be sure, buy certified hardware.

Just today at least three questions have come up for close-vote based on this.  I think it might be more productive to dupe them to a sort of "FAQ for supported hardware" question.

Should it exist?
If it does, what is the canonical question/answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many possibles:

- [Up-to-date hardware compatibility lists](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33969/up-to-date-hardware-compatibility-lists)
- [How do I know if a laptop will work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10958/how-do-i-know-if-a-laptop-will-work-with-ubuntu)
- [Which hardware manufacturers are more friendly to Ubuntu, besides Intel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169059/which-hardware-manufacturers-are-more-friendly-to-ubuntu-besides-intel)
- *<del>[deleted question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13920/best-hardware-for-a-ubuntu-computer)</del>*

Pick one.